# ffmpeg watermarking error : video pixel format unknown, Parser not found for codec

Tags: c#-4.0, ffmpeg, video-watermarking

I am trying to watermark my video but I am getting pixel format and codec errors.

I am using latest version of FFmpeg git-7d531e8 64-bit Static (Latest) (2011-12-12) from link http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

I am using the below code to add watermark to my video.

ffmpeg -i inputputfile.avi -target pal-vcd "movie=abc.png [Watermark]; [in][Watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" outputfile.avi.

But i am receiving the error of video pixel format unknown and parser  not found for codec error.

Later, I changed by code to add  codec and pixel format.

ffmpeg -i inputputfile.avi -vcodec wmv3 -pxl_fmt yuv420p -target pal-vcd "movie=abc.png [Watermark]; [in][Watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" outputfile.avi.

However I am still receiving the same error. Please help.

Comment: I used to make watermarks with vhook, but they deprecated it a long time ago. If you don't mind using an older version of ffmpeg, I can give you the command line for using watermarks with vhook.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question asked [at ffmpeg-user](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-September/002177.html), see if the answer there helps.